# Conditionally import/instantiate an object from an addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I'd like to make an addon that

1. imports config from the host app, then
2. inject + instantiates a class based on ENV vars

In particular I'm working with [Pretender](https://github.com/trek/pretender), and I want to be able to import the user's config from either their ENV or some object they `export` under `/app` in their project.

Then, if the environment is not `production` and there's no `--proxy` argument that was passed to the `ember serve` command, I want my addon to inject and instantiate a Pretender server with the user's config.

Is this possible?